# Is there any evidence on the effect of China's investment in African countries on their economic development?

Tags: development-economics, infrastructure

Apparently, China made substancial investments in infrastructure and commodity extraction in several African countries over the last couple of decades. Is there some econometrically sound evidence of the effects on growth or other economic variables?

See this, for example: [CNN posting on Kenyan Railway](http://www.cnn.com/2016/05/15/africa/kenya-railway-east-africa/)